how to input long vowel letter ॠ (ṝ) in devanagari keyboard layout?
I am learning Sanskrit and installed both Devanagari-INSCRIPT and -QWERTY keyboard under windows. However, I could NOT find a way to input the long vowel letter ॠ (ṝ).
Thank you for your help in advance.

On an iPad, shift ह, then press and hold ॠ

Does Option Shift ृ work for you in Inscript?

On a desktop PC under Microsoft Windows in Devanagari-INSCRIPT you enter the short ऋ (ṛ) by holding the ↑Shift key and hitting the +/= key, and the long ॠ (ṝ) is entered by holding simultaneously the ↑Shift and the right Alt (a.k.a. AltGr) keys and hitting the same +/= key.
The keyboard chart in the link I gave above is interactive, by hovering the cursor over the ↑Shift and AltGr keys you can see how the available symbols are affected by holding these keys:

The corresponding vowel diacritics are entered in a similar manner, only without holding ↑Shift: ृ by just hitting +/= and  ॄ by holding AltGr and hitting +/=.
